# vue-chartjs v4 reference to the chart object

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

```
chartjs v3.7.1
vue-chartjs v4.0.4
```

in version 3 of vue-chartjs, I could reference the chart object with `this.$data._chart` because the component is extends from the chart component.

but in version 4, it just uses the chart component directly, how do I get a reference of the chart object? I tried the :ref directive, but it only return the dom element, not the chart object.

and I couldn't find any example with v4.0.4

Comment: It's not possible in v4 because the [`Chart` instance is a local variable in `setup()`](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/blob/65762c8/src/BaseCharts.ts#L124), and it's not exposed as a public property.

Comment: This is no longer correct - it seems that the chart instance can be obtained using the ref: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts. It is accessible at `myref.value.chart`

Answer (score 0):

After toying around with the same/similar problem myself, I found a solution for me:

No, idea if it's an ok solution, or if I am breaking with some core principles whatsoever, since tony19 wrote, that the chart instance is not exposed as public property. So, please, keep that in mind.

I am using (among others):

- vue: ^3.2.33
- vue-chart-3: ^3.1.8
- chart.js: ^3.7.1
- chartjs-plugin-zoom: ^1.2.1

and I want to call `resetZoom()` on my chart. For that, I need that chart object to call that function on. I assume, that's the same chart object you are looking for? If not, please, comment, and I can delete the answer.

I my vue file I got something like:

```html
<template>
  <BarChart ref="mychart" />
</template>
```

And then I call in the function of my reset-zoom button:

```js
resetZoom() {
  const r = this.$refs.mychart as any;
  r.chartInstance.resetZoom();
}
```

So: using a `ref` to get the object, and then `chartInstance`

Comment: Yes, it works in vue-chartjs v3, but not v4 (current at version 4.0.7)